# fetch the number of record from a JSON file using shell

Tags: shell

I have a test.txt file in this format

```
{
 "user": "sthapa",
 "ticket": "LIN-5867_3",
 "start_date": "2018-03-16",
 "end_date": "2018-03-16",
 "demo_nos": [692],
 "service_names": [
    "service1",  
    "service2",
    "service3",
    "service4",
    "service5",
    "service6",
    "service7",
    "service8",
    "service9"

 ]
}
```

I need to look for a tag called demo_nos and provide the count of it.
For example in the above file "demo_nos": [692] which means only one demo nos...similarly if it had "demo_nos": [692,300] then the count would be 2

so what shell script can i write to fetch and print the count?

The output should say the demo nos = 1 or 2 depending on the values inside the tag [].

i.e I have a variable in my shell script called market_nos which should give me it's count

Comment: have you tried something already ?

Comment: currently I am trying to figure out a way to get that data to my other script that i was preparing, so any suggestions might be helpful.

Comment: "A text file in JSON format" is what's also known as "a JSON file"; there's no need for the longer verbiage, since *all* JSON files are also text files.

Comment: BTW, you might evaluate which answers still work when `"demo_nos":` and `[692],` items are no longer on the same line as each other.

Comment: anyways it worked using the below linux command, will try the other ways as well and let you know.....thanks for the answer anyways!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but this should do it

```
cat test.txt | grep -o -P 'demo_nos.{0,200}' | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1 | awk -F',' '{ print NF }'
```

Please note that this is a quick and dirty solution treating input as raw text, and not taking into account JSON structure. In exceptional cases were "demo_nos" string would also appear elsewhere in the file, the output from the command above might be incorrect.

Comment: what output do you get when you run that?can you explain a bit on what is this doing?

Comment: For example I get "3" when run with a test.txt file that contains eg "demo_nos": [692,555,4444]
The `grep` removes the string before demo_nos, then the `cut`s get the part inside [ ], and finally awk is counting the tokens separated by ","

Comment: ok so this data inside the tags they keep changing i.e. for example "dem_nos":[1,2,3].....so thee count is three like that it can be 2 or 4 or 5 so is there any way we can just grep the  demo_nos.{$,$} number of fileds?? i hope you are getting me??

Comment: Have you tried my command? Is it NOT returning what you need ?  Otherwise you can follow @Shawn answer using jq

Comment: (Ooh, the pure-awk approach above was a bit off; should have been `gawk '/demo_nos/ { print(split(gensub(/.*"demo_nos": \[([^]]+)\].*/, "\\1", "g"), arr)); }'` to actually do the split and return the count).

Comment: @Charles Answer updated acknowledging incorrectness in some cases.

Comment: (thumbs-up); now-irrelevant comments removed (will kill this one as well, in a bit).

Answer (score 1):

The gold standard for manipulating JSON data from the command line is [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq '.demo_nos | length' test.txt
1
```

`.demo_nos` returns the value associated with the `demo_nos` key in the object, and that array is piped to the `length` function which does the obvious.

Comment: Agreed, but jq tool might not be available/installed

Comment: yes it's not i used the one liner command above and its working.However using shell for all this is really hectic should use python.....anyways thanks to all..

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have python and the file is JSON :)

```
$ cat some.json
{
 "user": "sthapa",
 "ticket": "LIN-5867_3",
 "start_date": "2018-03-16",
 "end_date": "2018-03-16",
 "demo_nos": [692],
 "service_names": [
    "service1",  
    "service2",
    "service3",
    "service4",
    "service5",
    "service6",
    "service7",
    "service8",
    "service9"

 ]
}

$ python -c 'import sys,json; print(len(json.load(sys.stdin)["demo_nos"]))' < some.json
1
```